# Binding with StringFormat on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm doing some Windows Phone 7 development and want to format a string I've bound to.

For some reason I cannot use the StringFormat like shown below. The option just isn't there.

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Distance, StringFormat=\{0\}km}" />
```

Why isn't the StringFormat available for Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StringFormat was added with 7.1 / Mango since Mango uses SL4.  An example from [Visual Studio Magazine](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/12/01/10-reasons-to-upgrade-to-the-windows-phone-sdk-71.aspx):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentDate,StringFormat='dddd, d MMMM yyyy'}" />
```