# Bind text and variable value togheter

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-7, binding

How can use this text value?

```
Text="My custom text: {Binding MyData}"
```

In this code?

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lbl_data" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
 Margin="50,39,130,0" FontSize="13.333" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" 
 Text="My custom text: {Binding MyData}" 
/>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a Converter and pass in the Parameter MyData

If it was Silverlight 4.0 you can inherently use Value Converter like this

```
<Button Content={Binding MyData, StringFormat='My Custom Text \{0\}'}/>
```

Also Refer Question : [Binding with StringFormat on Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567119/binding-with-stringformat-on-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 1):

Use run:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lbl_data" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
       Margin="50,39,130,0" FontSize="13.333" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" 
       ext="My custom text: {Binding MyData}">
<TextBlock.Text>
     <Run Text="My custom text:" />
     <Run Text="{Binding MyData}" />
</TextBlock.Text>
```

Comment: "Property 'Text' doesn not support values of type 'Run'.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, but since I was looking for a similar solution I will post my answer too.
I didn't want to use a converter and I'm using .NET 4.5 with WPF - so it doesn't really apply to the original question. `<Run></Run>` did work for me as mentioned [in the question above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6223958/1234000)

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lbl_data" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
 Margin="50,39,130,0" FontSize="13.333" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26"/>
    <Run Text"My custom text: "/>     
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=MyData}"/>
</TextBlock>
```